# Modify /etc/passwd file without logging in

Tags: grub, system-recovery

I was experimenting with the /etc/passwd file in my Ubuntu 18.04. I rebooted my machine to check whether the changes are affected. But unfortunately my login screen is not showing up.

The screen displays Ubuntu loading screen and crashes automatically. How can I revert the changes made?

Comment: Boot a live system and mount the harddisk.

Comment: Read this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery